# Where is better to parse json string in AsyncTask Class?

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-asynctask

I get a **json** **string** from a **url** . this **json** is a larg number of datas and i must `parse` them and show in a **ListView** .

Now in your opinion i should

1 `Parse` them in **doInBackground()** method and return values

OR

2 Return **Json** String from **doInBackground()** without any change to parse in **onPostExecute()** ?

> I did it in **doInBackground()**  : Parse **Json** String in this method and get String values from **Json** String and Return Values . this work fine But when i `parse` this **Json** String in **OnPostExecute()** i can't get any thing

Comment: I think its better to do in doInBackground() ... for better performance use Gson to parse json

Comment: Just wanted to add, that if you need to reflect any results of your network operations in the UI, AsyncTask is a bad solution for this, since it's not tied to your Activity lifecycle in any meaningful way.

Comment: @ Alex Berdnikov , why you say AsyncTask is bad for this work ?

Comment: @Sabeer Mohammed Thanks , pls tell me about Gson and why have better performance ? 
share a tutorial link for Gson please .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to `Parse` the `JSON` in `doInBackground()` otherwise you will face a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Normally the behavior of `AsyncTask` is that

1. `onPreExecute()` you display something for the user to understand that something is happening/loading at the background.
2. `doInBackground()` execute your network call and get/send data
3. `onPostExecute()` you display the data in the widgets of your App.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: i think about your sentence number 2 . i used `doInBackground()` for getting network data as you said but my problem is about parsing json in this method ? 
why `doInBackground` is better than `OnPostExecute` for parsing json String

Comment: because this is how AsyncTask is designed

Comment: Thanks for replay 
your answer is clear and useful

Comment: your welcome. glad for being able to help

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion everything what does not need to run in the UI-Thread should not run in the UI-Thread.
So I would recommend to do to parsing in the `doInBackground()` method.

If the Json you are going to parse is received from a REST-API think about using the [Retrofit library](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). This will remove a big amount of boilerplate code :)